# Adding different colors to points manually in seaborn

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to assign colors to points manually. Like point1 should have dark blue, point 2 should have light blue, point 3 should have lighter blue, How I can do that in seaborn. Thanks

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {'OS_Packages':[0,1,2,4], 'Vulnerabilities': [6,7,3,7], 
     'text':['point1','point2','point3','point4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

p1 = sns.relplot(x='OS_Packages', y='Vulnerabilities',data=df )
ax = p1.axes[0,0]
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    x = row[0]
    y = row[1]
    text = row[2]
    ax.text(x+.05,y,text, horizontalalignment='left')
```

Comment: Use `plt.scatter` and set the colors via the `c` argument.

Answer (score 0):

What you seek from your explanation is a Sequential color palette.

```
sns.palplot(sns.color_palette("Blues"))
```

Alternatively, you can define a custom color palette in Seaborn.

```
flatui = ["#9b59b6", "#3498db", "#95a5a6", "#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71"]
sns.palplot(sns.color_palette(flatui))
```

The list item values need to be the color you wish to have in the hex format.
In your dataframe define a color map column which maps the data point to the desired color. Use your customer color map as a parameter in the plotting function.

Please use the Seaborn documentation for reference.

Comment: Thanks but how I can use it with the combination of relplot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.  The `hue=` parameter to `sns.relplot` controls the color of each item. `hue` can either directly control the color (as in this example) or via an indirection, for which you need a palette. I added `legend=False` to prevent showing a legend as `hue` here directly shows colors.  Many variations are possible.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {'OS_Packages':[0,1,2,4], 'Vulnerabilities': [6,7,3,7],
     'text':['point1','point2','point3','point4'],
     'colors': ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

p1 = sns.relplot(x='OS_Packages', y='Vulnerabilities',data=df, hue='colors', legend=False )
ax = p1.axes[0,0]
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    x = row[0]
    y = row[1]
    text = row[2]
    ax.text(x+.05,y,text, horizontalalignment='left')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

Here is an example that includes one type of palette together with a legend.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {'OS_Packages':[0,1,2,4], 'Vulnerabilities': [6,7,3,7],
     'text':['point1','point2','point3','point4'],
     'risk': ['high risk', 'medium risk', 'low risk', 'low risk']}

colors = {'high risk' : '#0000AA', 'medium risk' : '#7777DD', 'low risk' : '#9999FF'}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

p1 = sns.relplot(x='OS_Packages', y='Vulnerabilities',data=df, hue='risk', palette=colors)
ax = p1.axes[0,0]
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    x = row[0]
    y = row[1]
    text = row[2]
    ax.text(x+.05,y,text, horizontalalignment='left')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

Result: [image]

Comment: Did his answer your question?